# data-url with x-x509-user-cert does not work

Tags: google-chrome, data-uri

I am issuing certificates in a web application.
The key pair is generated in the browser using the keygen tag.

Then the certificates is directly put into the resulting webpage using a dataurl like this:

```
<a href="data:application/x-x509-user-cert;base64,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">Install
    Certificate to Browser</a>
```

This works perfectly fine in firefox.
But it does not work in chrome.
When clicking the link in chrome the certificate is displayed.

Obviously there is some mimetype confusion.

Do you have any idea, how the certificate must be displayed for chrome to install it as personal certificate?

Thanks a lot
Cornelius